# importing MdSelectModule causes angular build failure

Tags: angular, angular-material2

When I try to import `MdSelectModule` angular I face lots of build errors:

```
import {MdSelectModule} from '@angular/material';
```

Here is the content of package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "sbmclient",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10"
  }
}
```

And result of build reports lots of errors like this:

```
    ERROR in D:/.../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/scroll/scrollable.d.ts (1,49): Mo
dule '"D:/.../node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

ERROR in D:/.../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/scroll/scroll-dispatcher.d.ts (10
,42): Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

ERROR in D:/.../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/overlay/overlay-directives.d.ts (1,78): M
odule '"D:/.../node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.
```

Is there anything wrong with my package file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is that the **Renderer2** just exists from the [**Angular 4.0.0 rc.1**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc3-2017-03-10%60) and you're using Angular **4.0.0 beta 3**.

Also, it's mentioned [**here**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta3-cesium-cephalopod-2017-04-07) that since the version `Angular Material 2 (beta 3)` it depends on Angular 4.0.0 and you're using **Material2 beta 5** with Angular **4.0.0 beta 3**. So it may not work because, as you can see in the Angular's *CHANGELOG* (link above), **Renderer2** was called **RendererV2** before the **rc.1 version**).

---

**Solution:** Update `@angular/*` *packages* to the latest (including `@angular/compiler-cli` ~this is really old~).